Use TS Generics for a object using another object key and value type
I'm having some trouble using Generics in typescript.
I want to create an object based on another object type using Generics.
My starting point was this doc from TS
This is what I have come up so far:
type ClickableItem<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T> = {
  label: string;
  key: K;
  render?: (value: T[K]) => string;
   // The value (argument) type here should reflect the type from the selected key
};

The current outcome
If I try to use this ClickableItem type in an object, I get the argument type of render union of all possible type values, for example:

type Example = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

const item = {
  label: 'x',
  key: 'a',
  render: (value) => value //ERROR HERE
} satisfies ClickableItem<Example, keyof Example>


The render method is inferred incorrectly to type string | number even tho the key a is specifically set to type string
In the example prior, the type of the method render should be (value: string)=> string instead of the inferred type (value: number | string)=> string.
Here's the ts playground link including the original example from TS's Doc and my test implementation mentioned prior

{
  label: 'x',
  key: 'a', 
  render: (value) => value
}

Is not a subtype of ClickableItem<Example, keyof Example> so it will not satisfy it here.

ClickableItem<Example, keyof Example> expands to this type:
type MyType = {
  label: string;
  key: 'a' | 'b'
  render?: (value: string | number) => string;
};

Put another way, your code is identical to:
const itemFromSatisfies = {
  label: 'x',
  key: 'a',
  render: (value) => value //ERROR HERE
} satisfies {
  label: string;
  key: 'a' | 'b'
  render?: (value: string | number) => string;
}

Note how there is no connection between the key and the render function. That's effectively lost because you passed in keyof Example as K so you get one object type that would work for all keys of T.
But your object cannot handle all keys of T. It can only handle the string ones since render must return a string, and you are simply return the raw value, so that much start as a string.

Instead, you want a union that has one member for each property.
type ClickableItemUnion<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ClickableItem<T, K>
}[keyof T]


type MyTest = ClickableItemUnion<Example>
// ClickableItem<Example, 'a'> | ClickableItem<Example, 'b'>

This mapped type creates a union for every property of T where the key and render properties can be strongly paired up one at a time.
Now you do this and it will work:
const itemFromUnion = {
  label: 'x',
  key: 'a', 
  render: (value) => value
} satisfies ClickableItemUnion<Example>

This is because this object matches the one member of the union where the key is 'a' and the render function accepts a string.

So given all that, we can simplify this back down by using a mapped type that yields a union from the start:
type ClickableItem<
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends keyof T
> = {
  [P in K]: {
    label: string;
    key: P;
    render?: (value: T[P]) => string;
  }
}[K];

This type maps whatever union of keys that are requested, and yields union for each one.
So now:
type MyType = ClickableItem<Example, keyof Example>

is identical to:
type MyType = {
    label: string;
    key: "a";
    render?: ((value: string) => string) | undefined;
} | {
    label: string;
    key: "b";
    render?: ((value: number) => string) | undefined;
}

And so can be used in your satisfies constraint with any issue:
const item = { // fine
  label: 'x',
  key: 'a', 
  render: (value) => value
} satisfies ClickableItem<Example, keyof Example>

See playground

Thank you @Alex, it works perfectly!
Using the [P in K]: { (...) }[K] was a nice hack I haven't seen before.
Nice trick.

You're welcome. But I wouldn't call that a hack. It's just a mapped type
